# Copy an Observable into an existing observable

Tags: android, rx-java

In my application, I have an Activity where an Observable is subscribed to listen to some new data.
This Observable comes from a Controller of the Activity.

The Controller is responsible of fetching some data and giving it to the Activity through this Observable.

When the controller is asked to fetch some data, it first fetches data in a DB, gives the DB's data to the Activity and then perform a Retrofit request to fetch some more recent data and gives this new data to the Activity.

The source of the data should be transparent for the Activity, a single Observable is used.

So, whenever the Controller fetches some data from either the DB or with Retrofit, he should "gives" to the Activity Obervable all the new data.

How can I copy an Observable values into another already existing Observable ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about concatenating the two observales?

```
public class DataController {

    public Observable<Item> fetchData() {

        Observable<Item> fromCache = // creates the observable reading from cache
        Observable<Item> fromNetwork = //creates the observable reading from network

        return Observable.concat(fromCache, fromNetwork);
    }
}
```

Comment: What if, for an unknown reason, the network answers comes faster than the cache ? I will try your solution anyway :)

Comment: I'm not a RxJava guru but AFAIK concat doesn't interleave the events. So you will receive the events from network after the cache observable completes. See the diagram: http://rxmarbles.com/#concat

Comment: So the order of the parameters of concat() actually matters. Awesome. That's what I was looking for ! Thx. Very nice website to understand the operators by the way.